# Fragment.OnStop is not called while Activity.OnStop is called

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have `ActivityA` which contains `FragmentF`.
`ActivityA` contains also NavigationDrawer infrastructure.

When I start the app - all is fine.
There are called (among others):

```
ActivityA.OnStart
FragmentF.OnStart
ActivityA.OnResume
FragmentF.OnResume
```

.. and content is shown.

But when I press home (to minimize app & show home screen) - here comes the problem:
`ActivityA.OnStop` **is** called
`FragmentF.OnStop` **is NOT** called

Interesting facts:
- if I switch items in NavigationDrawer then `FragmentF.OnStop` **is** called and content of another fragment is loaded in `ActivityA`
- in all cases (minimize the app & switch content in NaviDrawer) `FragmentF.OnPause` is always called

As a workaround I put code (expected to work in `OnStop`) to `OnPause` but wondering:
- why `FragmentF.OnStop` is not called
- how to make it called

I'm using Xamarin (thus `CamelCase` namie convention :) - but I don't suspect this platform for bug, it seems like Android native behavior.

Comment: First of all, I do not know what kind of specific layout in your project or use other  plugins. I test it in my demo(Activity contains Fragment).https://github.com/851265601/FragmentDemo When i click the home button, `Onstop` of Fragment was called like screenshot in this demo, can you share your demo? This issue may related other reasons, do you use `Util.log` to generate it and capture the log in logcat, Note: Don't put time-consuming operations in `OnPause`

Comment: I tested your project - Frag.OnStop is called on my device (emulator Android 5.0 / API 21). Seems sth must be in my project. Tnx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I do not know what kind of specific layout in your project or use other plugins. I test it in my demo(Activity contains Fragment).

github.com/851265601/FragmentDemo

When i click the home button, `Onstop` of `Fragment` was called like screenshot in this demo. This issue may related other reasons, do you use `Util.log` to generate it and capture the log in logcat. Note: Don't put time-consuming operations in `OnPause`

Comment: @Grzegorz Dev Do you have any updates? If the reply help to you, please mark the reply as answer.

Comment: Lu - great, great tnx for your answer, but this answer does quick workaround for problem and not fixing it (still in some cases Fragment.OnStop is not called although Activity.OnStop is called). Really, really sorry but I think it's not final answer - but I give you +1 for big help